# Customizing a TabControl for the Closing of Individual Tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls, tabcontrol

### My scenario is the following:

I am working on a winforms application in C# that has a button inside the main page of a tabcontrol that will generate another tabpage each time that it is clicked. Each new tabpage will contain a layout defined by a user control.

### My Questions are:

1. How can I allow the user to then close one of the tabs that were created dynamically at runtime?
2. How might I go about modifying the tabcontrol itself so that it has a small 'X' in each tab that the user may click on in order to close that particular tab? (Like Firefox has)
3. How can I expose the SelectedIndex property of the tabcontrol to the user control if I want to close the tab with a button inside the user control instead?

Comment: I've use this in the past, and it actually worked quite well: [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/firefoxtabcontrol.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/firefoxtabcontrol.aspx)

Comment: Did any of the answer help? If it did, please accept one.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a derived tab control about one year ago. I am not going to post the source here, because it's about 700 lines long and coded quite messy. Maybe I will find some time to clean the code up and then release it here. For now I will briefly outline the way it is build.

Each tab page has a 'X' icon to the *left* of the title and the tab pages support reordering by drag and drop and moving them between multiple tab control.

I choose the easy way to get the icon on the tab pages. The tab control has the [`TabControl.ImageList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.imagelist.aspx) property and a tab page has a [`TabPage.ImageIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.imageindex.aspx) property. So I just added three icons to a image list - normal, hover, pressed - and  process the mouse events.

With [`TabControl.GetTabRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.gettabrect.aspx) you can test if the mouse is over a specific tab pages and with some math you find if it is over the icon. Then you just need to change the icon depending on the mouse button state and eventually remove the tab page under the mouse if the button was pressed.

The main problem with this solution is, that calculating if the mouse is over the icon requires to know where the icon is painted relative to the tab page and this might change with a new windows version. And the icon is to the left of the title, but that does not look too bad.

Comment: I did not. Unfortunately I do even no longer remember which project included that control. I will do a search through to projects I can still easily access but chances are slim because the project probably got archived some time ago.

Comment: No luck. I guess the project was still in SVN but was archived during the migration to TFS.

Comment: That's Okay Mate. I will pull up my sleeves and will do it. Will post code sample when done. Thanks for all your effort.

Comment: Red X to the _left_, ey? I prefer the _right_, because it just seems logical to me :)

Answer (score 14):

I found this code and was very helpful to me:

```
private void tabControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // check if the right mouse button was pressed
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        // iterate through all the tab pages
        for(int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
        {
            // get their rectangle area and check if it contains the mouse cursor
            Rectangle r = tabControl1.GetTabRect(i);
            if (r.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                // show the context menu here
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TabPressed: " + i);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

[TabControl: How To Capture Mouse Right-Click On Tab](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e09d081d-a7f5-479d-bd29-44b6d163ebc8)

Answer (score 6):

I did the following: 
on the create (add) `TabPage` stage, I added a `toolStrip`

```
ToolStrip ts = new ToolStrip();
ts.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
ts.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
```

Then, create the `X` button and add it to `toolstrip`

```
ToolStripButton ToolStripButton = new ToolStripButton("X");
ts.Items.Add(ToolStripButton);
```

create an event on clicking the `X` button

```
ToolStripButton.Click += new EventHandler(ToolStripButton_Click);
```

add `toolstrip` to the `tabpage`

```
tabControl1.TabPages[curenttabpage].Controls.Add(ts);
```

**now**  for the `ToolStripButton_Click` is as follows:

```
void ToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 ToolStripButton t = (ToolStripButton)(sender);
 ToolStrip ts = t.Owner;
 TabPage tb = (TabPage)
 (ts.Parent);tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tb);
}
```

Maybe it is not as you want, but it will work well.

Comment: Great answer.  I would add that, if you intend to have another control on the tab page with DockStyle.Fill, you need to add the ToolStrip ~after~ that control or the ToolStrip will cover the top portion of it.  This cannot be fixed by calling BringToFront or SendToBack on the 'fill' control.

Answer (score 2):

I created a setup that is similar.

Each control that is added to the tab page at runtime is derived from a special base control I created.  This base control has a close button (along with some other features such as safe to close flag).

Close tab code I'm using on my base control:

```
 TabPage tabpage = (TabPage)this.Parent;
TabControl tabControl = (TabControl)tabpage.Parent;

tabControl.TabPages.Remove(parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I did find this [link](http://www.syncfusion.com/FAQ/windowsforms/faq_c93c.aspx#q642q) that will allow you to "hide" tabs in an array and then you can just re-load the tabs you want at run time. I added this more for a place I can easily find it again.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help throgh closing the tab controls with middle mouse click :

```
            private void tabControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Button != System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle)
                    return;

                for (int i = 0; i < MainTabControl.TabPages.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (this.MainTabControl.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location))
                    {
                        this.MainTabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

It´s works!

```
TabPage tabpage = (TabPage)this.Parent;
TabControl tabControl = (TabControl)tabpage.Parent;
tabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabpage);
```