# how can add button on tab page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have try a complete firefox in windows form application. I add some add tab page but can't a close by click. I have no idea to paste a cross button on the tab page.My coding part is :-

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text == "+")
        {
            AddNewTab();
        }
        foreach (Control item in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(WebBrowser))
            {
                WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)item;
                toolStripButton1.Enabled = wb.CanGoBack;
                toolStripButton2.Enabled = wb.CanGoForward;
            }
        }
        this.wb.DocumentTitleChanged += Browser_DocumentTitleChanged;
        this.wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
    }
```

[image]

my closed function--

```
 private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab != null)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

this function is closed the tab page by double click , I want to closed the tab page with the help of button same as FireFox working

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to close a tab, is that your question?

Comment: i have make the closed function but i want a button create help of closed the tab page...sorry for waiting

Comment: Why aren't you associating the close function you made with the event handler of the button then?

Comment: Just i want to  add a cross bar every tab page.

Comment: Oh, you mean the 'x' to close it?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183352/close-button-in-tabcontrol and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803540/customizing-a-tabcontrol-for-the-closing-of-individual-tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is outside the scope of the [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx).

To do this, you would need to create a [Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In your custom control, you could add a small [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) with the image of a <kbd>+</kbd> and some text on a [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) and several [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) controls.

Code the <kbd>+</kbd> [Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) to call your closing technique.

Code the [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx)'s [Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) to show different [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx)s in your form with your HTML pages.

**EDIT:** Like Brian was kind enough to point out below, here is an excellent tutorial on how to do this on CodeProject:

[CodeProject: FireFox-like Tab Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20050/FireFox-like-Tab-Control)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: plz can you share a coding part

Comment: Thanks Brian. To @j.s.banger: Creating a custom control is not exactly trivial and the code would need to be specific to your application (i.e. **Custom**).

Comment: Did you click on the link that Brian provided? It has an excellent tutorial showing how to do exactly what you are trying to recreate.